# how to turn off conversion currency

Tags: magento2, multicurrency, conversion

I have two views for my website.
A view for Europe and another for the Swiss.

Currencies are different but the problem is i would like to choose prices for each view.
Currently, prices for my second view are converted automatically.

So, i would like to know how to turn off this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Stores Configuration -> Currency -> Currency Rates and check to see if currency exchange values have been entered. If so, set the exchange rate for Swiss to 1.0 (equal to Euro).
You can still set the currency and price for each product using the Store scope switcher to set the price for Euro then Swiss. Since the exchange rate will equal across all currencies, no conversion will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to || admin panel>stores>configuration>currency setup || and then set the  Base Currency and Default Display Currency as the same currency inputs . Then run the cache clean and refresh the page the issue is resolved.